# A trigonometric proof of an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

We have  $f(x) = \sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(...\cos x)...))))$, where $5$ $\sin$ and $5$ $\cos$ are side by side.

Prove, that $|f(\frac15) - f(\frac{1}{10})| \le  \frac{1}{10}$

I simply have no idea how to use anything to prove the statement, is it connected to odd or even functions, or some famous $\sin - \cos$ connections?

The question is maybe a duplicate, if so I am sorry, thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\left|f\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)-f\left(\tfrac{1}{10}\right)\right|\leqslant \frac{|f'(\xi)|}{10}
$$
for some $\xi\in[\tfrac{1}{10},\tfrac{1}{5}]$ by the mean value theorem. And it is straightforward to check that $|f'(\xi)|\leqslant 1$.

Comment: Just one comment, $ \le 1 $ comes from the main attitude of $sin$ and $cos$, that their absolute value is always $ \le 1 $, so their combination can't be bigger than $1$?

Comment: Also, $f'(x)$ will be the combination of $sin$ and $cos$ as well right?

Comment: Exactly! This is not really a "trigonometric" proof but it's the only thing I could come up with.

Comment: Above all, it comes from the chain rule!

Answer (score 5):

Both $\cos$ and $\sin$ have derivative bounded by $1$ in absolute value; therefore both satisfy a Lipschitz condition with constant $1$, and so does any $\circ$-composition of these functions.

Answer (score 4):

The map:
$$ \varphi: x \to \sin(\cos x) $$
is a [contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) of the interval $[0,1]$. Since:
$$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \left|\varphi'(x)\right| = -\varphi(1) = \cos(1)\sin(\sin 1)=0.7216\ldots<\frac{3}{4}\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$ \left|\left.\varphi^{(5)}(x)\right|_{\frac{1}{10}}^{\frac{1}{5}}\right|\leq\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{10}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^5<\frac{1}{42}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Wow, that is a very nice proof :)